# How can I keep my, distance representing, score field and map it into my resulting entity?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, geolocation, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using the following query:

```java
NativeSearchQuery nsq = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(qb)
    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, PAGE_SIZE))
    .withSort(sb)
    .build();
```

With the following SortBuilder:

```java
SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort("customer.address.geoLocation",
         customer.getAddress().getGeoLocation().toGeoPoint())
    .order(SortOrder.ASC)
    .unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
```

Which is producing the desired sort query:

```
"sort": [
  {
    "_geo_distance" : {
      "customer.address.geoLocation" : [
        {
          "lat" : 40.4221663,
          "lon" : -3.7148336
        }
      ],
      "unit" : "km",
      "distance_type" : "arc",
      "order" : "asc",
      "validation_method" : "STRICT",
      "ignore_unmapped" : false
    }
  }
]
```

Aditionaly each resulting document is returning the distance to to the reference parameter in km:

```
"sort": [2.4670609224864997]
```

I need this value as part as my domain but I simply cannot push it into my object. I tried a simple approach as definig it into my domain as what it seems to be a `float[]` but I keep getting null. I'm using Jackson for (de)serializing.

```java
  private float[] sort;

  public float[] getSort() {
    return this.sort;
  }

  public void setSort(float[] score) {
    this.sort = score;
  }
```

My repository:

```
  public interface ElasticsearchProductRepository 
        extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {
    Page<Product> search(SearchQuery searchQuery);
  }
```

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Document(indexName = "product", createIndex = true, type = "_doc")
@Setting(settingPath = "elasticsearch/product-index.json")
@DynamicTemplates(mappingPath = "elasticsearch/product-dynamic-templates.json")
public class Product {

...

  @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
  @javax.persistence.Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @JsonView(ResponseView.class)
  private long id;

  @Field(analyzer = "autocomplete", type = FieldType.Text, searchAnalyzer="standard")
  @JsonView(CreationRequestView.class)
  private String productName;
  private float[] sort;

...

  public float[] getSort() {
    return this.sort;
  }

  public void setSort(float[] score) {
    this.sort = score;
  }

}
```

I added the following scripted field:

```
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": {
        "lang":   "painless",
        "source": "doc['sort']",
        "params": {
        }
      }
    }

}
```

But it is not finding the sort field.

`"reason": "No field found for [sort] in mapping with types []"`

It seems that doc references doc._source in reality... how can I reference this great piece of data from an Elastic script?

Comment: can you please add the definition of your `Product` class?

Comment: Added thee relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in Spring Data Elasticsearch the returned entity is populated from the values returned in the *_source* field. The returned *sort* is not part of that, but a part of the additional information return for each search hit.

For the next release (4.0) we are currently in the process of rewriting how returned hits are handled. The next version will have a `SearchHit<T>` class where `T` is the entity domain class, and the `SearchHit` object contains this entity along with other information like score, highlight, scripted fields, sort etc.

It is planned that the repository methods then can for example return Lists or Pages of these `SearchHit` objects.

But currently, the sort from the query will lead to a sorted return, but you cannot retrieve the sort values themselves - which in your case is bad, because they are calculated dynamically.

**Edit:**

You can retrieve the value by defining a property for the geo_distance in your entity and annotate this with the `@ScriptedField` annotation, and then provide the script in your native query. An example can be found in the  at [tests for Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/ff381c63b6d7633a7a17b3d8a63db36661763afe/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java#L798). This example works with the `ElaticsearchTemplate`, but it should make no difference passing this query into a repository search method.

**Edit 25.12.2019:**

The current *master* branch, which will become Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0, has this implemented. The found documents are returned in a `SearchHit` object that also contains the *sortValues*.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Is there any way to, for example, script the distance value into my _source field to parse it into the entity? I willy stay in the lookout for 4.0 at the same time.

Comment: Updated my original question, I cannot seem to reference this field from a scripted field script.

Comment: Alternative is `doc['customer.address.geoLocation'].planeDistance(33.818445,-84.555139)` but it seems like I'd be calculating the distance twice, once to sort and once to field.

Comment: Also while doing that the rest of the _source dissapears, and cannot find any spring-data equivalent for my nativequery that does something like this:

  "fields": [
    "_source"
  ]

Comment: Nothing worked for me, I ended up copying and extending DefaultResultsMapper and injecting it into the constructor of my ElasticsearchRestTemplate; then hardcoding my class.

Comment: @dElo this is now implemented see, my edited answer

Comment: Looking forward to update and refactor on SNAPSHOT @P.J.

Comment: keep in mind, that we are currently still working on this, so this is not a final API yet. If you like to try it out, we are glad to get feedback